# I have read a lot of (the?) blog posts you wrote

Tags: articles, definite-article

Should it be "I have read a lot of the blog posts you wrote" or "I have read a lot of blog posts you wrote"?

I guess I can also say "I have read a lot of your blog posts"?

Comment: The first and third sentences mean exactly the same thing. The third sentence is the most natural of the three. The second sentence is odd and has a slightly different meaning, but I can't quite put my finger on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read a lot of the blog posts you wrote

This sounds perfectly normal to me.

> I have read a lot of blog posts you wrote

**This is grammatical**, however, when spoken, it sounds, at least to me, as if it's lacking something. You can either add the definite article before "blog posts" or add the relative pronoun "that"/"which" after "blog posts". But that's just my personal preference.

> I have read a lot of your blog posts

This also sounds perfectly normal to me.

Unfortunately, I don't have any other sources other than my ears.